# AngularJS - How to access $scope from a directive with specified scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive which has got it's own scope which accepts values from the directive's DOM attributes but there are a few vars from the `$scope` which I want to access from the directive too. Can anyone help me to do this.

Here is my directive and how I use it.

```
appDirectives.directive('appTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/templates/template.html',
        scope: {
            template: '='
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="template in templates" ng-click="chooseTemplate(template)">
    <app-template template="template"></app-template>
</div>
```

And this is the template of the directive and here I have template value but I want also to access `$scope.rootPath`

```
<div class="template">
    {$ ???scope.rootPath??? $}
    {$ template is accesable $}    
</div>
```

Comment: where do you plan on getting the value of rootPath? Is it an attribute, from a service, specific to the directive code, etc?

Comment: It's a constant global for the project and I am storing it in the $scope. Because of this I want to access it from the directive without the need to copy/paste it everywhere

Comment: which $scope is it in?  I don't see it in your directive and since you've defined a scope in your return object you have created an isolate scope for this directive.  You can expose it via a link function, but could you add the part of your code that accesses the rootPath property?

Comment: What is stopping you to pass `rootPath` as an attribute to the isolated scope of directive? `scope: { template: '=', rootpath: '@' }` inside directive. and then pass in the rootpath as attr where the directive is used?

Comment: @Matt Pileggi: rootPath is in the controllers scope but I am passing template value and making local scope for the directive. Maybe the link function will save me and I won't need this local scope..

Comment: @dmahapatro: I was going to do it this way but I am not sure is there any other way to access it because if I have more vars to acces I have to pass them all.

Comment: Yes, that is the beauty of isolated scope which makes the directive reusable without polluting the parent scope or other models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use is with isolated scopes as well:

```js
appDirectives.directive('appTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/templates/template.html',
        scope: {
            template: '=',
            rootPath: '='
        },
    }
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="template in templates" ng-click="chooseTemplate(template)">
    <app-template template="template" root-path="rootPath"></app-template>
</div>
```

… and then access it as usual:

```html
<div class="template">
    {$ rootPath is accesable $}
    {$ template is accesable $}    
</div>
```

There are probably other solutions but this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The is exactly how you go about passing objects into a isolate scope. If your controller is in the parent of your directive then the directive will inherit the functionality of the controller.

Unless you need it to have an isolated scope, for example each template in templates has their own unique values then you can pass it in as an object like you are doing now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you don't have to declare local scope for the directive, the attributes are accessible without it. After omitting the scope declaration it will work, and the directive will look like this:

```js
appDirectives.directive('appTemplate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'partials/templates/template.html',
        transclude: true
    }
});
```

The other way, which will also work, is to inject the $scope.rootPath to the directive as a parameter.

Comment: Nice one. By the way - the "transclude: true" is not related to the fact that omitting the isolated scope will get you access to controller's scope.

Regarding $rootScope inside the directive: it is possible and will work, but it is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have `appTemplate` prototypally inherit from the parent scope and use `$parse` for the `template` attribute.

```
app.directive('appTemplate', ['$parse', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var templateGet = $parse(attrs.template);
      scope.$watch(templateGet, function(value) {
        scope.template = value;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

It sees all variables from the outtermost scope (`templates`, `rootPath` etc) but does not really depend on the name of the iteration variable in the `ng-repeat`. So both this:

```
<div ng-repeat="template in templates">
  <app-template template="template"></app-template>
</div>
```

and this:

```
<div ng-repeat="t in templates">
  <app-template template="t"></app-template>
</div>
```

works without any modification.

Caveats:

1. If `ng-repeat` is defined as `ng-repeat="t in templates"` just because you already have a variable called `template` which is needed in the children scopes, you are effectively doomed because `appTemplate` overrides it internally (this does not affect parent variable, whatsoever)
2. If `appTemplate` is meant to edit data that have been inherited, those data have to be at least a 2nd level property (`customer.firstName`, not `firstName`). This is a general caveat with scope inheritance.

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ohG4J5LcLhNW3fjYw7UW?p=preview).